# Create Clip from embedded videos on my app using YouTube APIs

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to add a feature to my web app that enables the users to create clips from embedded YouTube videos on my app without bothering going through YouTube itself.
Is there any tool available? Couldn't find anything on the YouTube API docs.

I'd like to use YouTube APIs (even if other tools are available), specify the start and end of the clip, then receive the new video id as the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately YouTube APIs don't give the ability to create clips.

However you can create an algorithm to create clips automatically:

To generate clips automatically, first you need to make a test clip to initialize the mechanism, but before clicking on the button `Share clip`, open your web-browser developer `Network` tab (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`E` on Firefox) and filter (if possible) `XHR` then click on `Share clip`. You should see a request to `create_post`, right-click it and copy it as cURL.

At the end of this command there are interesting arguments:

- `commentText` it is the clip description
- `externalVideoId` it is the video id you are clipping
- `offsetMs` is the start of the clip in milliseconds
- `durationMs` is the duration of the clip in milliseconds
  You can freely modify these arguments to generate a clip automatically without using YouTube UI.

Remove `-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br'` from the command in order not to have the following warning notifying us of *the absence of output* at the command execution:

```
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
```

Then execute the modified command, you should get a JSON response, the interesting entry of it is `actions/0/shareEntityServiceEndpoint/serializedShareEntity`, as it contains a base 64 of the generated clip id and some other stuff.
The clip is the 36 length id similar to `UgkxbH81RHU_yyYr1cq2oUrcVtPfTFU-Zumx`.