# What format is the data in the clipt parameter?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to programatically generate YouTube embed URLs using standard YouTube URLs. I'm having trouble generating embed URLs for [Clips](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/10332730?hl=en). The `clipt` parameter is not listed in [Google's documentation of YouTube embedded player parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

`https://www.youtube.com/embed/qVqV5T45QB0?clip=Ugkx97OCpf318BJnwKLlPj48mCBSes4MBD3w&clipt=EAAYiCc`

The part after `/embed/` is the ID of the original video. `clip` is the ID of the clip. `clipt` appears to be the start time and end time of the clip, however, I do not know what format this number is in. The embed URL above has a start and end time of 0:00.0 - 0:05.0.

- `EAAY7Cc` is the value for a start and end time of 0:00.0 - 0:05.1.
- `EAAY0Cg` is 0:00.0 - 0:05.2
- `EAAYtCk` is 0:00.0 - 0:05.3
- `EAAYmCo` is 0:00.0 - 0:05.4
- `EAAY8C4` is 0:00.0 - 0:06.0
- `EAAY2DY` is 0:00.0 - 0:07.0
- `EGQY8C4` is 0:00.1 - 0:06.0
- `EMgBGPAu` is 0:00.2 - 0:06.0
- `EKwCGPAu` is 0:00.3 - 0:06.0
- `EOgHGPAu` is 0:01.0 - 0:06.0

I have attempted to decode these numbers as base64, base58, base32, and base16; none of the outputs looked correct.

[An explanation of the format for video IDs is available here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54443/format-for-id-of-youtube-video/101153#101153). Even while using this document, I was unable to solve how to convert "0:00.0 - 0:05.0" to `EAAYiCc`

Comment: Doesn't [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76200578) solve your problem, despite not understanding `clipt` format?

Comment: Actually it seems Protobuf encoded, you can find the notes I took about this topic [here](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/190).